# In a Tizen web app, can i use javascript web worker to run background code on a closed application?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker, tizen, tizen-web-app

I need to create an web application in Tizen that needs to get the user location either the application is open or it's closed. I found that i  can run javascript web worker to run code in a diferent thread, but i don't know if with the web worker i can run the code with the application closed. If it can't, there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [`background-support`](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/app_dev_process/editing_tizen.htm) attribute, but the app would still need to be running.

> **background-support**
>
> Used to define whether the execution of the Web application continues when the application is sent to the background.
>
> This attribute is optional. The default value is **disable**.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I found that you can also create a Hybrid Application, combining a Tizen native aplication as a background service with the web aplication. 

https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/articles/accessing-native-audio-playback-and-recorder-controls-web-applications